# Regex to match CSS structure?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex that will help me clean up large files. I want to change this:

```
selector {
  property: value;
}
```

into this:

```
selector { property: value; }
```

including similar versions like:

```
selector,
selector2 {
  property: value;
}
```

into:

```
selector,
selector2 { property: value; }
```

but not change:

```
selector {
  property: value;
  property2: value2;
}
```

Basically, I want to find where there is only one instance of the `property: value;` and change that but leave everything else alone.

NOTE: There can be instances where there are differences such as tabs, 2 spaces, 4 spaces, etc used for indentation. I would like to catch all of these if possible.

Comment: I don't think a regex is really a proper tool here. It might be better to get a css formatter or roll a minimalistic parser

Comment: you also dont specify a language so this is kind of pretty broad

Comment: The CSS formatters that I have have different styling preferences and digging through all their code seemed less worthwhile than trying a quick regex.

Comment: I didn't think I needed to specify a language. I gave the examples and if it doesn't fit into those examples I don't want anything to happen.

Comment: @o_O Daniel Grosskopf and I have provided a couple of answers; did either of those meet your needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, regex isn't necessarily the best way to do this. That said, here's an incompletely-tested regex that will do the trick for you.

Replace:

```
\{\s+(\S+:)\s*([^;]+;)\s+\}
```

With:

```
\{ $1 $2 \}
```

For example, this works in Notepad++ or Sublime Text. If you are using a scripting language (Perl, PHP, JavaScript, whatever), you may need to explicitly add the `g` flag to the regex to replace all matches, as in `/\{\s+(\S+:)\s*([^;]+;)\s+\}/g`

[Here's a working demo](https://regex101.com/r/aV7wZ2/1).

Comment: Where do you specify a newline? Also, `[^;]` covers a wide spread of characters, including newline.

Comment: @sln `\s` matches any whitespace, including new line characters (`\n`). You are correct that `[^;]` is too broad; I'm going to tweak that.

Comment: I would guesstimate there is no guarantee of a newline using `\s`, since it is a class of characters.

Comment: @sln not sure what you mean by that. The `\s` class includes `\n` (as well as `\r`, `\t`, and a simple space) by definition.

Comment: I believe he is looking for at least a newline before and after the prop/val. As it is now the regex will also match `{ property: value; }` Unless, you will match all forms, including single newline before/after.

Comment: @sln yes, true, but that's harmless. We're talking about a one-off find-replace; the performance penalty for matching the example you gave will be negligible unless he is processing an enormous amount of text that contains huge numbers of lines formatted that way.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about performance, more on form. If form is not whats needed, a blind  `\{\s*([^:;]*:[^:;]*;)\s*\}` is all that's needed. Matches, only single prop/val pairs.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will work to find what you are looking for:

```
\{\n.+?\n\}
```

I would use this regex in Sublime Text 2 in order to clean up your files by following these steps:

1. Open your file in Sublime Text 2
2. Press Ctrl+F
3. Click the button on the far left of the search bar to turn regex searching on.
4. Enter the regex formula I gave you.
5. Hit Alt+Enter to select all areas in the document that match this pattern.
6. You can now edit with the multiple cursors functionality.  Example keystrokes to do what you want would be left arrow, end, delete, end, right arrow, backspace.

Comment: This will not work if the file has any other whitespace characters after `{` or before `}` (including `\r`, which is part of the line separator `\r\n` in Windows). Also, OP is asking for a regex-based solution to both find and replace the styles in question. Your answer only tells OP how to do it manually.

Comment: True, though it's simple enough to change.  Also I tested this on windows computer and Sublime Text 2 recognizes line breaks as "\n" and not "\r\n" interestingly enough.  Really my aim was to keep it simple, OP might need a steak knife or he might need a machete, it's not clear from his question.  You provided the machete, I provided the steak knife.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do it like this.
Basically, its just getting and excluding line breaks;

Find:  `\{\s*\r?\n\s*([^:\r\n]*:[^;\r\n]*;)\s*\r?\n\s*\}`
Replace:  `{ $1 }`

Formatted:

```
 \{ \s* \r? \n \s*                # { then newline
 ( [^:\r\n]* : [^;\r\n]* ; )      # (1), property: value;
 \s* \r? \n \s* \}                # newline then }
```